# promesas en firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

estoy trabajando con firebase real time,y tengo un problema al obtener un valor dentro de una promesa, pues quisiera que ese valor se me almacenara en una variable global

```
   firebaseService.database().ref('Users/' + us.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    let dato = snapshot.val().countShops
    fun(dato);
     })

var dat = {};

function fun(dato) {
    console.log(dato);
    dat = dato;
}
console.log(dat);
```

al hacer el ultimo console, no me muestra la info, pues aparece vacio el objeto, pero si miramos el console log dentro de la funcion fun si me muestra el valor correctamente.
He estado leyendo y parece que tengo que hacer una funcion async, pero la verdad he intentado y no he podido, apenas estoy aprendiendo sobre promesas

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que al ser una promesa, no podes mostrar el log antes de que termine.

### Como funciona

Al hacer un request de lectura o escritura a la base de datos con una promesa, esta se comporta similar a un `valueEventListener` que usamos con Firebase, este tipo de peticiones son asincronas, esto quiere decir que mientras tu promesa se ejecuta, el bloque que viene a continuacion va a ser ejecutado.

Entonces lo que tenes que hacer es lo siguiente, ejecutas la promesa, la cual tiene 3 estados

- Pendiente
- Fullfilled (Que se pudo realizar)
- Rejected (No se pudo    realizar, aca debemos usar un catch o
  retornar otro valor)

Luego que ejecutas la promesa, tenes que esperar a que el valor que vas a buscar sea retornado para mostrarlo con el `console.log` , de otra manera el console log se va a ejecutar antes de que la promesa termine y siempre vas a tener null.

Como veo en tu codigo, estas ejecutando el console.log fuera de la promesa sin antes esperar a que los datos sean traidos.

Por lo que deberias solucionarlo poniendo ese console.log dentro de la funcion que ejecutas en tu promesa

```
function fun(dato) {
    console.log(dato);
    dat = dato;
    console.log(dat);
}
```

De esta forma, la funcion `fun(dato)` va a contener el valor de dat para ser asignado al `console.log` de otra forma nunca lo puedes acceder si no lo tienes.

Recorda que cada promesa debe devolver un catch o return , ya que necesitas manejar los 3 estados de la misma , por lo que tu promesa deberia quedar asi. Recuerda de usar `exists()` para preguntar antes de mandar el dato a tu funcion si existe en esa referencia , de lo contrario siempre terminarias con otro null

```
var dat = {};

  firebaseService.database().ref('Users/' + us.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    let dato = snapshot.val().countShops
    fun(dato);

   }


 }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Ocurrio un error al traer los datos");
  });

function fun(dato) {
    console.log(dato);
    dat = dato;
    console.log(dat);
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo, ahora entiendo un poco mas